# Java - Masking out sign bit causes unexpected behavior

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have the following value:

```
int x = -51232;
```

Java integers are 32 bits, so in binary this should be the following:

```
10000000000000001100100000100000
```

The sign bit on the left is set to `1` since `x` is negative.

Then I do the operation

```
x = (x & Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `2147483647` and in binary that would be:

```
01111111111111111111111111111111
```

0 on the left because the value is positive.

So why does `x & Integer.MAX_VALUE` yield `2147432416`? The `AND` operator should only retrieve bits that `x` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` have in common, which should be equivalent to `-x` (since they do not share the same sign bit).

What's going on here?

Comment: -51232 is `11111111111111110011011111100000` and not `10000000000000001100100000100000`. Java works with [two's complement](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), not a simple sign bit.

Comment: The question is well-answered below, but what is your intent in this manipulation?  Is ```Math.abs(x)``` a better fit to your requirements?

Comment: `Math.abs` by contrast has the fun property that it can have a negative result, unlike AND-ing with MAX_VALUE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your misunderstanding is caused by lack of knowledge regarding how negative integers are represented in binary in Java. You should read about 2's complement.

`10000000000000001100100000100000` is **not** the binary representation of `-51232`.

`11111111111111110011011111100000` is.

And when you run bitwise AND, you get:

```
11111111111111110011011111100000 (-51232)
01111111111111111111111111111111 (Integer.MAX_VALUE)
--------------------------------
01111111111111110011011111100000 (2147432416)
```

Here's the binary representation of -51232 next to the binary representation of 51232. You can see that their sum is 2<sup>32</sup>. that's always the case with 2's complement, for any pair of `int`s `x` and `-x`.

```
00000000000000001100100000100000 (-51232)
11111111111111110011011111100000 (51232)
```

Answer (score 0):

Integers are stored in two complement: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement.

Thus while the leftmost bit indicate negative numbers, it is not really a sign bit as it would be for floating point numbers in common representation.

The main reason of this representation is that it make it easy to do addition and substraction among other at the hardware level.

One should not that with two complement notation, -1 is represented by all bit set to 1.